# Intersection of Dictionary based on keys and values

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary

I have a couple of dictionaries that I want to perform intersection on.
two dictionaries might have different lists of values for the same key.

Example:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> Primary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
Primary.Add(1, new List<int>());
Primary[1].Add(5);
Primary[1].Add(6);
Primary[1].Add(7);

Primary.Add(2, new List<int>());
Primary[2].Add(5);

Dictionary<int, List<int>> Secondary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
Secondary.Add(1, new List<int>());
Secondary[1].Add(6);
Secondary[1].Add(7);
Secondary[1].Add(8);

Secondary.Add(3, new List<int>());
Secondary[3].Add(5);
```

So I want the resultant dictionary to contain only:

> [1],[list<6,7>]

How can I achieve this? The actual data structure where I want the intersection is of the form:

```
Dictionary<long, SortedList<int,List<long>>>
```

Comment: Which part of this are you struggling with? What have you tried?

Comment: If a key exists in both dictionaries but the corresponding lists have no common items, would you want the result to contain that key with an empty list?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, if they have the same keys but no common items in list, it should give null. The answer given by BartoszKP works perfectly for Dictionary<int, List<int>>. I'm trying to extend it for Dictionary<long, SortedList<int,List<long>>>. Its confusing

Comment: @romkyns Well, I can write nested FOREACHs where i iterate through each key and check if the key contains in secondary and so on. But its a long procedure and may not be optimized. Hence i'm looking for better way, like the one suggested by BartoszKP, for the complex data structure that i mentioned -  Dictionary<long, SortedList<int,List<long>>>

Comment: I asked you if you wanted an empty list and you said yes, you want null.  Null is not an empty list.  An empty list is a list that's empty and null is no list at at all.  If the answer provided suits your needs then you want an empty list, not null.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry, i need an empty list.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry, i need an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this as follows:

```
var result = Primary.Keys.Intersect(Secondary.Keys)
                 .ToDictionary(key => key,
                               key => Primary[key].Intersect(Secondary[key]).ToList());
```

Transforming the result into `Dictionary<long, SortedList<int,List<long>>>` should be easy enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Its working for the datastructure Dictionary<int, List<int>>.  It would be really great if you could help me out for the other data structure as well - Dictionary<long, SortedList<int,List<long>>> - because I'm relatively new to this method and it's driving me bonkers! :(

Comment: @Sabz You can achieve it in exactly the same manner, by analogy. Btw. you should create a class instead of building such complicated, nested structures. They are inconvenient, unreadable and thus - error prone.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using linq for the first time so i'm finding it confusing. Also, I did consider creating classes instead of dictionaries but it would be difficult to perform these intersections.

Comment: @Sabz Everyone has been there so don't worry. Just start with some simpler tasks/tutorials so it will be easier. Consider accepting this answer if it was helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Thank y ou very much for your time. I'm still trying to figure out the code for intersecting the other data structure